# Does Software Updater sync up changes with apt-get update/upgrade?

Tags: apt, package-management

Instead of clicking the `update` button on the Software Upgrader, I've just been running `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y`. This doesn't seem to be "registering" in the Software Updater though. E.g., the Software Update has just told me that I have 300 MB or so of updates even though I've been running the `apt-get update` and `apt-get update` commands.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some software that will not be installed by `sudo apt-get upgrade`.  To cause this other software to be installed, run the command

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Comment: Let me run that really quick and see what I get.

Comment: This appears to have downloaded the packages that were scheduled to be upgraded from Software Updater.

Does this mean that I should run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` to get the same functionality as hitting "update" on the Software Updater?

Comment: You could leave out the middle command -`dist-upgrade` does both, but is a somewhat scarier command to use.